Modify the UltraVNC's Message Box of lost connection
Description of equipments: (optional to read)
I've got the PC #1 with the UltraVNC client with the Windows10 and with two LCD screens. First LCD screen is right next to the PC #1 and second screen is 15 meters away of the PC #1.
Another PC #2 is PLC HMI device with UltraVNC host with the Windows 7 and here on screen are displayed important information which I need to mirror on the PC #1's second LCD screen via uvnc.
Why via unvc? Beacuse the PC #2 is connected to the PC #1 via cable network adapter and PC #2 has no free video port to connect it with the second LCD screen.
Description of issue:
On the PC #1 I have a preconfigured .vnc file which allows me to auto open uvnc session on the second LCD screen.
After I open the .vnc session it is running ok. But from time to time it is necessary to restart the PC #2 and then after 10 or 20 seconds on the PC #1 it will appears a "VncViewer Message Box" and uvnc session will freeze.
When I will spotted on the second LCD screen that the session is freezed then I must walk to the PC #1 and press "Close" button.
If I press "Close" button too soon the whole session will close. Or if I'll wait until PC #2 will boot after restart then I'll press "Close" button then the uvnc session will be resumed.

Questions:
Is it possible to delay of display that "VncViewer Message Box"?
Or is it possible to disable of display that "VncViewer Message Box"?
I've checked uvnc's parameters but I didn't find anything useful.
https://uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer/52-ultravnc-viewer-commandline-parameters.html

Did you actually find a solution for that?

unfortunately not
